# Actionscript 3: How do I get all classes using one enter frame function?

Tags: function, actionscript, frame, enter

I'm making an adventure game in AS3 and have many classes. I heard it is best for performance if there is only one Enter Frame function and all update functions run from that.

I currently have a mainGameLoop in my main.as, what is the best way for all my classes to contain an update function running from this single enter frame function?

Here is an example of what I've done to run an update function in my Player class, but I don't like this solution at all.

If anyone could help it'd be much appreciated, thanks.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    // Initialising variables...
    private var m_SceneHandler:SceneHandler;
    private var m_UserInput:UserInput;

    public function Main()
    {
        // Adding main update function...
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop );

        // Creating the scene handler...
        m_SceneHandler = new SceneHandler();
        addChild( m_SceneHandler );
    }

    private function mainGameLoop( event:Event )
    {
        doUpdate();
    }

    private function doUpdate():void
    {
        // Update player...
        if (m_SceneHandler.m_aCurrentScene[0].m_Player)
        {
             m_SceneHandler.m_aCurrentScene[0].m_Player.doUpdate();
        }       

}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this approach. What don't you like about it?

Comment: A scene isn't always going to be running, hence the if statement. I guess I didn't like the main class talking to the player.

I decided the main update function would run an update function in m_SceneHandler, and then inside that it runs an update in the current scene and then inside that it runs an update in the player.

Seems more extensible by having it just drill down like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the composite pattern and code to an IUpdateable interface.

```
package view {
   public interface IUpdateable {
      function doUpdate():void;
   }
}
```

In your main game loop, just switch out which object(s) should be updated:

```
package{
   public class Main extends MovieClip implements IUpdateable {
     protected var updateChildren:Vector. =  new Vector.();
     //other logic would manage who is currently updateable and who is not
     public function doUpdate():void {
        for each (var updateable:IUpdateable) {
           updateable.doUpdate();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Then, if there are subcomponents that need to update, they could also be IUpdateable, and the higher level IUpdateable could call the method.